# SSRS Error - tablix ‘Tablix1’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder, ssrs-grouping

I have a question regarding SSRS reports. It might be related to Grouping but not sure it will solve my problem.

There is letter for customer and he might pass 2- 3 classes. So each customer can have 1, 2 or 3 classes. Now when I do it in the normal way it shows student 1 data 2 times if he passes two classes. I need to see all the classes in one letter for a student.

Here is the letter:

> XXX,
>
> Rajagopal, Blair Platinum, India.
>
> This is your certification of appreciation.
>
> Here are the classes you passed
>
> Class1 Botany Course - 132
>
> Class2  Zoology Course - 536

Instead it shows as:

> XXX,
>
> Rajagopal, Blair Platinum, India.
>
> This is your certification of appreciation.
>
> Here are the classes you passed
>
> Class1 Botany Course - 132
>
> XXX,
>
> Rajagopal, Blair Platinum, India.
>
> This is your certification of appreciation.
>
> Here are the classes you passed
>
> Class2  Zoology Course - 536

Please help me so that I can see all the classes in one letter.

Answer:  I did a subreport for the class 1 class 2 and added it to the main report and it worked

Comment: Akarsh Did you get what Chirs means

Comment: I did a subreport for the class 1 class 2 and added it to the main report and it worked

Answer (score 3):

Create a group based on the person and have the rows above the class line in the group header. Set it to have a new page per group.

Then the detail page just has the class section.

You can put any letter sign off in the group footer.

Comment: I did a subreport for the class 1 class 2 and added it to the main report and it worked